# When do compositions of isogenies of elliptic curves respect isomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves

> Let $E/ F_p$ be an elliptic curve. Let $G_A$, $G_{A'}$, $G_B$ and $G_{B'}$ be subgroups of $E(\overline{F_p})$. Suppose $E/G_A \simeq E/G_{A'}$ and $E/G_B \simeq E/G_{B'}$. When is $E/<G_A,G_B> \simeq E/<G_{A'},G_{B'}>$?

The above question was my attempt at finding necessary and sufficient conditions that an elliptic curve $E'$ (upto isomorphism) should satisfy so that the following diagram commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    E @> \phi_A>> E/G_A\\
    @V \phi_B  V V @VV  V\\
    E/G_B @> > > E'
\end{CD}
I am assuming that all of these are cyclic isogenies and $(\deg \phi_A, \deg \phi_B)=1$. I wanted to say that $E'$ makes the diagram commute iff $(y-j(E')) | gcd(\Phi_{l_2}(j(E_A),y), \Phi_{l_1}(j(E_B),y))$, where $\Phi_i$ is the $i$-th modular polynomial and $l_1$ and $l_2$ are the degrees of the isogenies $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$, resp. But this doesn't seem enough considering my original question.

Comment: This is just a question for abelian groups.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you. Can you describe what conditions should be satisfied by the isomorphisms $\phi_A: E/{G_A} \simeq E/G_{A’}$ and $\phi_B: E/{G_B} \simeq E/G_{B’}$ in order to guarantee the last isomorphism.

Comment: Have a look into the isomorphism theorems. Might be helpful.